# Determine usb debugging enabled or not when connected with device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

HI i am working with **xamarin android** i am trying to determine using my app that when my app **connected with device USB debugging** enabled or not i am trying to use below code but cannot find

```
Settings.Secure
```

I want to use below code

```
int adb = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 0);
```

Please if i am right how can i use it in my project if not then what's the other way

Answer (score 2):

`Settings.Secure.AdbEnabled` and `Settings.System.AdbEnabled` were deprecated in API 17 and moved to `Global`

```
int adb = Settings.Global.GetInt(ContentResolver, Settings.Global.AdbEnabled, 0);
```

Ref: [ADB_ENABLED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#ADB_ENABLED)

Note: This does not determine if the Debug Bridge is active or not.

If you are looking for when a debugger is attached you can use:

```
Log.Debug("SO", $"Java Debugger: {Android.OS.Debug.IsDebuggerConnected}");
Log.Debug("SO", $"Mono Debugger: {System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached}");
```

Comment: @SushilHangover..i am trying to use below code but not working is it also depricated  int adb = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
  Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 0);

Comment: @stylishCoder Refer back to my answer, use `Settings.Global.....` not  Settings.Secure.. or Settings.System...

Comment: @SushilHangover.. i am not able to use settings.system or global i.e nothing comes after system..actually i am trying to enable usb debugging if it is disabled....am doing it right or wrong..can you please let me know whats the exact syntax??

Comment: @SushilHangover.. yes its my typo mistake after writting settings. only two options comes refrenceEquals and Equals...

Comment: @stylishCoder The `Setting` you are looking for are contained in the  `Android.Provider` namespace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123006/discussion-between-stylishcoder-and-sushihangover).